# obtener datos tras ejecutar un script de cmd o powershell con c#

Tags: c#, cmd, powershell

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa para monitorizar (cpu, hdd, gpu, fan, etc) de mi pc y mandarlas a una app en mi telefono, en teoría con la ayuda de cmd o powershell con el comando winsat se puede hacer, ya estuve haciendo pruebas por fuera de visual studio y al parecer podría funcionar

**¿existe alguna librería para eso?**

Comment: ¿Que especificamente quieres monitorear?

Comment: los componentes de mi computadora (ventiladores, cpu, gpu, etc), las velocidades, temperatura, cosas de ese estilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para obtener la salida de cualquier comando por medio del ventana de commando utiliza algo asi.

```
// Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "YOURBATCHFILE.bat";
 p.Start();

 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar.